# HTML: How to get a calculation result before executing a function

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I have a script that I am trying to execute. I need the script to, on the press of the submit button:

1. fetch values from Google firestore
2. Use those values in a calculation
3. use the result of this calculation to write back to the firestore database

I have put `console.log("eff[1,2,3]" + result of calculation)` to help trace in the console log the order of execution. It first displays `eff3` then `eff1` then `eff2` so this means that the value submitted to firestore is zero (as it is before the calculation) The calculation does calculate the correct answer it just doesn't submit the answer to the database.

How do I change my code to have it execute in the right order?

```
// Triggered when the send new message form is submitted.
function onMessageFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Calculate efficiency
  var preodo = 0
  var efficiency = 0
  firebase.firestore().collection('Vehicle').doc(reg.value).collection('Refuels').orderBy('Date', 'desc').limit(1)
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
        preodo = change.doc.data().Odometer
        efficiency = (odo.value - preodo) / amount.value
        efficiency = efficiency.toFixed(4);
        console.log("eff1:" + efficiency)
      });
      console.log("eff2:" + efficiency)
    });
  //Save refuel transaction with all details form the form as well as the calculated efficiency        
  console.log("eff3:" + efficiency)
  saveMessage(reg.value, odo.value, date.value, amount.value, price.value, rebate.value, efficiency).then(function() {
    window.alert('Refuel submitted!')
    // Clear message text field and re-enable the SEND button.
    resetMaterialTextfield();
    toggleButton();
  });
}
```

Comment: my guess, never having used Google Firestore, would be that the `onsnapshot` method is asynchronous but your code is running the `savemessage` method in a synchronous fashion. Can you add a `Promise` to the `onSnapshot` method and use the resolved value to continue the program flow?

Comment: Can you not just move the `saveMessage` code up - to after the "eff2" line?

Comment: @carljdp, if I do then it submits the save multiple times as if it's in a loop

Comment: @JillianWittstock, i see. I don't have more advice (yet), [perhaps this can be helpful](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) in debugging further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore operations are asynchronous, so you'll need to handle them with a promise. Do exactly what you did with `saveMessage()`, but with returning a value

Also, use `.get()` instead of `.onSnapshot()`, as the latter will continue to listen to changes made to the referenced document, which you don't need because you do this operations when a button is clicked.

```
function get_efficiency(regValue) {
    efficiency = -1
    // return a Promise which will return the efficiency after all computations are done
    return firebase.firestore().collection('Vehicle')
        .doc(reg.value)
        .collection('Refuels')
        .orderBy('Date', 'desc')
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshots) { // this will execute after all documents are fetched from the db
            querySnapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
                preodo = doc.data().Odometer
                efficiency = (odo.value - preodo) / amount.value
                efficiency = efficiency.toFixed(4);
                console.log("eff1:" + efficiency)
            });
            console.log("eff2:" + efficiency)
            return efficiency
        })
}


// Triggered when the send new message form is submitted.
function onMessageFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Calculate efficiency
    var preodo = 0
    var efficiency = 0

    get_efficiency(reg.value)
        .then(function (efficiency) { // this will execute after you computed the efficiency
        // efficiency param is the one returned from the PROMISE from get_efficiency()
    
        //Save refuel transaction with all details form the form as well as the calculated efficiency        
        console.log("eff3:" + efficiency)
        saveMessage(reg.value, odo.value, date.value, amount.value, price.value, rebate.value, efficiency).then(function() {
            window.alert('Refuel submitted!')
            // Clear message text field and re-enable the SEND button.
            resetMaterialTextfield();
            toggleButton();
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using @Professor Abronsius' suggestion, I put my code in a `Promise`

```js
// Triggered when the send new message form is submitted.
function onMessageFormSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    //Calculate efficiency
    var preodo = 0
    var efficiency = 0
    firebase.firestore().collection('Vehicle').doc(reg.value).collection('Refuels').orderBy('Date', 'desc').limit(1)
      .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
          preodo = change.doc.data().Odometer
          efficiency = (odo.value - preodo) / amount.value
          efficiency = efficiency.toFixed(4);
          console.log("eff1:" + efficiency)
        });
        console.log("eff2:" + efficiency)
        myResolve(efficiency); // when successful
        myReject("Not able to calculate efficiency"); // when error
      });
  });

  // "Consuming Code" (Must wait for a fulfilled Promise)
  myPromise.then(
    function(efficiency) {
      //Save refuel transaction with all details form the form as well as the calculated efficiency        
      console.log("eff3:" + efficiency)
      saveMessage(reg.value, odo.value, date.value, amount.value, price.value, rebate.value, efficiency).then(function() {
        window.alert('Refuel submitted!')
        // Clear message text field and re-enable the SEND button.
        resetMaterialTextfield();
        toggleButton();
      });
    },
    function(error) {
      window.alert(error)
    }
  );
}
```

This works... It submits to the firestore only once but... it prints to the console log as follows:
`eff1`, `eff2`, `eff3`, `eff1`, `eff1`, `eff2`.

I'm now curious as to why it repeats itself? It doesn't really matter that it repeats this because it doesn't affect the database or the user interface but I am curious.

Comment: It seems to repeat the loop for every entry in the database so the second time I submit it does the loop 3 times, third submit loops 4 times and so on